execute php-file with post parameters
One a webpage there is a button / from is submitting a post request which calls via action
php_file_name.php?action=command.
Now I want to call this command from (bash) shell / cronjob.
P.S.: The PHP file is wp-admin/update-core.php  from Wordpress and the command is action=do-translation-upgrade. As Wordpress does not provide an auto update function for this and there are no hints in WordPress boards I just want to do my own script for that.
Running curldoes not generate an error - but also did not succeed:
curl -v -d 'action=command' https://xxxx/php_file_name.php. But maybe this is not a practical way anyway because of needing login to the website.
As I am on the web-server itself I am able to run execute the PHP file directly with any user / rights needed.
Solutions like this use a request to an URL instead of calling an executable file.
Maybe I need to transform the command in the post request to function parameters similar to here?

-d adds POST parameters to the request body. But you want a GET parameter instead - so append it to the URL.

"As I am on the web-server itself I am able to run execute the PHP file directly with any user / rights needed." - so this script is explicitly written in a way, that it does not require a valid user (WP user?), when executed via the command line? Via CLI you can not really pass POST parameters, so either the user check, or how this script receives the data, might need to be modified.

Anything hindering you from directly calling "php 'path to file'/update-core.php"? The only problem would be that you need to pass the action as parameter of this call which would be different than the web access.

If you are just trying to update the translations, try with WP-CLI
wp language core update
also try
wp language plugin update / wp language theme update

Ok - thanks a lot - sudo -u www-data -i -- wp language core update inside webshop directory did it.
